# why chrome dev tools debugger shows me jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web

I am trying to understand how other people's website's java script is working. Basically I can see that while **clicking** on an item, the properties of this item are displayed in other part of the window and I am trying to find an onclick handler that does this job (to debug and understand it). What I do:

1. Open chrome dev tools
2. Load the page
3. Go to sources tab
4. Press "Pause script execution"
5. Click on the item

But after this happens dev tools stops at this part

```
    var n = 0, r = function(e) {
        b.event.simulate(t, e.target, b.event.fix(e), !0)
    };
```

in the jquery-1.9.1.min.js. Now, I know that there is some custom java script code assigned to onClick event for sure, but don't understand why chrome debugger stops at some jquery code.

Comment: That's because jQuery is relaying the event. You would have to break in `trigger()` or `dispatch()` to see the final event recipient(s).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: jQuery does not directly register the event handlers you specify. Instead, it registers a "proxy" handler that allows it to sanitize the event object, call preDispatch hooks, support namespaced events, etc. That "proxy" handler, in turn, invokes the ones you registered. Have a look at [the events module's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js)